# What languages other than Python have an explicit self?

Tags: python, programming-languages

It seems a bit weird that Python requires you to explicitly pass `self` as the first argument to all class functions. Are there other languages that require something similar?

Comment: A correction wrt Python: it doesn't "ask you to explicitly pass self" when calling method, it is passed automatically as first param. But you must declare this first param in method definition.

Answer (score 5):

By explicit, do you mean "explicitly passed as an argument to each class function"?
If so, then Python is the only one I know off-hand.

Most OO languages support `this` or `self` in some form, but most of them let you define class functions without always defining `self` as the first argument.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your point of view, Lua.  To quote the reference: "A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar for v.name(v,args), except that v is evaluated only once."  You can also define methods using either notation.  So you could say that Lua has an optional explicit self.

Comment: how would you define  a method `foo(self, a, b, **kwargs)` in lua?

Comment: I'm not really an expert in Lua.  As far as I know, it doesn't have keyword arguments, but you could simulate their behavior by using the syntactic sugar for sending a table to the method.  Tables have an array like part and a hashlike part.

So define something like "function object:foo(args) a = args[1]; b = args[2]; self.argx = args.argx; end" and then call it with something like "object:foo{1, 2, argx=3}".

If you want an explicit self, you can define "object.foo = function(self, args) a = args[1]; b = args[2]; self.argx = args.argx; end" and then call "object.foo(object, {1, 2, argx=3})

Answer (score 4):

The programming language Oberon 2 has an explicitly *named* but not explicitly passed 'this' or 'self' argument for member functions of classes (known as type bound procedures in Oberon terminology)

The following example is an Insert method on a type Text, where the identifier 't' is specified to bind to the explicit 'this' or 'self' reference.

```
PROCEDURE (t: Text) Insert (string: ARRAY OF CHAR; pos: LONGINT);
BEGIN ...
END Insert;
```

More details on Object Orientation in Oberon are [here](http://www.statlab.uni-heidelberg.de/projects/oberon/kurs/www/Oberon2.OOP.html).

Answer (score 3):

F# (presumably from its OCAML heritage) requires an explicit name for all self-references; though the name is any arbitrary identifier e.g.

```
 override x.BeforeAnalysis() = 
    base.BeforeAnalysis()
    DoWithLock x.AddReference
```

Here we're defining an overriding member function `BeforeAnalysis` which calls another member function `AddReference`.  The identifier `x` here is arbitrary, but is required in both the declaration and any reference to members of the "this"/"self" instance.

Comment: In python you can also call the 'self' argument anything: `def method_name(self_evil_twin, *args)`

Answer (score 2):

[Modula-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-3#Object_Oriented) does. Which is not too surprising since Python's class mechanism is [a mixture of the ones found in Modula-3 and C++](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#).

Answer (score 1):

any [Object-Oriented language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) has a notion of this or self within member functions.

Answer (score 0):

[Clojure](http://clojure.org/) isn't an OOP language but does use explicit self parameters in some circumstances: most notably when you implement a protocol, and the "self" argument (you can name it anything you like) is the first parameter to a protocol method. This argument is then used for polymorphic dispatch to determine the right function implementation, e.g.:

```
(defprotocol MyProtocol
  (foo [this that]))

(extend-protocol MyProtocol String
  (foo [this that]
    (str this " and " that)))

(extend-protocol MyProtocol Long
  (foo [this that]
    (* this that)))

(foo "Cat" "Dog")
=> "Cat and Dog"

(foo 10 20)
=> 200
```

Also, the first parameter to a function is often used by convention to mean the object that is being acted upon, e.g. the following code to append to a vector:

```
(conj [1 2 3] 4)
=> [1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

many object oriented languages if not all of them

for example c++ support "this" instead of "self"

but you dont have to pass it, it is passed passively

hope that helps ;)

Comment: Not "passively" but "implicitly".  Like Java, the C++ compiler reasons out where `this` belongs.  Sometimes it will be unable to reason out if a `this` belongs in front of a variable reference, and you must put it in to resolve the ambiguous name.